# Work Calculus Question

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals

A chain weighing 5 lb/ft hangs vertically from a winch located 16 ft above the ground, and the free end of the chain is 2 ft from the ground. Find the work done by the winch in pulling in 2 ft of the chain.
 I know that W=f*d so I made an integral that was (5)(16-x) from 0 to 2 but it didn't work and I didn't get the right answer. If someone could help that would be great.

Comment: Essentially 10 pounds of chain lifted 13 ft. Do you really need to integrate?

Comment: Guess not.. the answer was 130ft